# How to represent a interchangeable relationship between two classes in UML class Diagram

Tags: java, uml, diagram

Suppose that F16Weapon and F18 HornetWeapon are the two weapon class.They have three weapon such as connon,bomb,missile for each class.

I am tiring to draw a interchangeable relationship between F16Weapon and F18 HornetWeapon.I mean F16 class can use F18 weapon set or F18 class use F16 weapon set. Basically If F16 class try to use F18 cannon weapon , F16 will use it easily from F18 Weapon set. Same thing will true for F18 class. So there  will an interchangeable relationship between F16 class and F18 class. How can I represent this interchangeable relationship between two class in UML class diagram ? Anyone can help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way is through class generalization like `class F16Weapon extends FxCompatibleWeapon..` and `class F18HornetWeapon extends FxCompatibleWeapon..`. Although it is usually more flexible from the decoupling point of view to use [interfaces...](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/design-pattern-abstract-factory-uml-class-diagram-example.html)

Answer (score 2):

xmojmr is right that you should use generalization.  The point behind his answer is that generalization is a way of pulling like behaviors from a group of classes and making them into one class that they all use.  This is pretty much what you have described here.

Now, if the cannon uses the same software when using the F16 and F18, then you might want to keep that software in one place and let both of them use it.  If, instead, you want them to use different software, and then use a third piece of software that deploys the cannon without having to know whether it's using an F16 or an F18, then you would use an interface.  An interface says if you want to be a CannonDeployer (or whatever) then you have to make a Deploy method (or whatever) available, but you can write it up any way you want.

So, as he says, an interface is more flexible, but you have to decide whether you need to go to the extra work of providing different implementations of the software for each plane.  If you don't, then put the implementation in the base class (FXCompatibleWeapon in xmojmr's example) and leave it at that.